# Using Underscore Count and Total Array Elements

Tags: underscore.js

Let's say I have these two JavaScript Arrays:

```
var types = ["w", "x", "y", "z"];

var data = [["x", 3], ["y", 4], ["x", 2], ["z", 6], ["z", 3], ["x", 1], ["z", 2]];
```

Using Underscore.js I want to produce these two results:

```
var counts = [["w", 0], ["x", 3], ["y", 1], ["z", 3]];

var totals = [["w", 0], ["x", 6], ["y", 4], ["z", 11]];
```

The counts array just counts the number of instances each element appears in the data array. The totals array sums up the elements that appear in the data array by type. I need the code to work even when there are elements in the types array that don't appear in the data array - as in this case there are no "w" elements in data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am simply looping (underscore way)

```
var types = ["w", "x", "y", "z"];
var data = [["x", 3], ["y", 4], ["x", 2], ["z", 6], ["z", 3], ["x", 1], ["z", 2]];
var counts = [];
var totals  = [];

_.each(types, function(type, index){
    var count = 0;
    var total = 0;
    _.each(data, function(value, index){
        if(type == value[0]){
            count ++;
            total += value[1];
        }
    });
    counts.push([type, count]);
    totals.push([type, total]);
});
console.log(counts);
console.log(totals);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your `data` array to a structure holding the different results:

```
var res = {};
_.each(data, function(item) {
    var r = res[item[0]] = res[item[0]] || {total: 0, nb: 0};
    r.nb++;
    r.total+= item[1];
});
```

will give you

```
res = {
    x: {total:6, nb:3},
    y: {total:4, nb:1},
    z: {total:11, nb:3}
}
```

You then map your `types` array to extract the desired format:

```
var counts = _.map(types, function(t) {
    return [t, res[t] && res[t].nb || 0];
});

var totals = _.map(types, function(t) {
    return [t, res[t] && res[t].total || 0];
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/wmo7br0u/